How to complete 24.10 release upgrade of snaps after `dpkg` crashed during installation?
Upon upgrading to Ubuntu 24.10 the release upgrade tool aborted early without reverting the install, saying that the installation had completed with errors. (In particular dpkg had crashed and I had to re-run it to get all the packages to finish installing.)
Notably, this was before anything to do with snaps upgrading happened. Running snap list on a machine where the upgrade did complete successfully yields
Name                       Version          Rev    Tracking         Publisher   Notes
bare                       1.0              5      latest/stable    canonical✓  base
canonical-livepatch        10.9.0           286    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
core22                     20240904         1621   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
core24                     20240710         490    latest/stable    canonical✓  base
desktop-security-center    0+git.84f197a    32     1/stable/…       canonical✓  -
firefox                    131.0-1          5014   latest/stable/…  mozilla✓    -
firmware-updater           0+git.5007558    127    1/stable/…       canonical✓  -
gnome-42-2204              0+git.510a601    176    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gnome-46-2404              0+git.5d6be1b    48     latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes          0.1-92-g83a94a1  1536   latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
mesa-2404                  24.0.9           143    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
prompting-client           0+git.d60470b    51     1/stable/…       canonical✓  -
snap-store                 0+git.4fcd62b7   1218   2/stable/…       canonical✓  -
snapd                      2.63             21759  latest/stable    canonical✓  snapd
snapd-desktop-integration  0.9              253    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
thunderbird                128.3.1esr-1     532    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -

whereas the borked machine reports
Name                            Version             Rev    Tracking         Publisher   Notes
bare                            1.0                 5      latest/stable    canonical✓  base
canonical-livepatch             10.9.0              286    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
core                            16-2.61.4-20240607  17200  latest/stable    canonical✓  core
core18                          20240920            2846   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
core20                          20240705            2379   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
core22                          20240904            1621   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
firefox                         131.0.2-1           5091   latest/stable    mozilla✓    -
gnome-3-34-1804                 0+git.3556cb3       93     latest/stable    canonical✓  -
gnome-3-38-2004                 0+git.efb213a       143    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
gnome-42-2204                   0+git.510a601       176    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
gnome-system-monitor            45.0                186    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes               0.1-81-g442e511     1535   latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
hunspell-dictionaries-1-7-2004  1.7-20.04+pkg-6fd6  2      latest/stable    brlin       -
pycharm-community               2024.2.3            414    latest/stable    jetbrains✓  classic
snapd                           2.63                21759  latest/stable    canonical✓  snapd
thunderbird                     128.3.1esr-1        532    latest/stable    canonical✓  -

Note for instance that core24 and gnome-46-2404 are missing. During the successful install the graphical tool said (during the snap upgrade part) something along the lines of "upgrading release channels" or something to that effect.
How do I do the equivalent of upgrading my "snap repositories" to the new release so that I can install the new software?

The snaps I'm missing seem to be those listed in the deb2snap.json file inside the release upgrade tool, consisting of entries which give dpkg packages and their snap replacements. I guess the easiest thing to do would just be to rerun the release upgrade tool manually by force. How do I do that?

Most snap packages are not touched during a release-upgrade, only the base snapd infrastructure (part of it anyway) as that is a deb package that of course changes with release-upgrade. One of the benefits of snap packages is they'll run on any release; ie. the core18 package you have listed allows snap packages compiled with for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to run on your system, core20 likewise for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS etc... ie. those are independent from the actual release you're using.

Thanks for the info, but I'm not sure I quite believe you: for the last (few?) releases I've noticed the progress bar in the graphical update tool go from 0%-50% as all of the dpkg stuff is handled, and then 50%-100% with explanatory text referencing various snaps on the system (accompanied by various large chunks of network utilization). I'm pretty sure some standard, automated thing is going on there with individual snaps like gnome-46-2404 getting installed.

Aha -- found it. See https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-desktop-s-24-10-dev-cycle-part-4-august-update/47217 . There IS now snap seeding during release-upgrades, as of 24.10.

There is no comparable activity to updating an apt repository.
Simply use snapd to install the missing snaps (if you wish -- they are optional) and to ensure you are on the desired track (like "stable"). After that, the snaps will auto-update.
It may be wise for future readers to check that corresponding deb files ("deb" lines) in the deb2snap.json seed file (/usr/share/ubuntu-release-upgrader/deb2snap.json) have been removed. Many snaps don;t have deb files to remove, so read carefully. For example the transition from 24.04 to 24.10 added new snaps, but those snaps did not replace any debs.
It's not worthwhile to duplicate the snap-seeding that occurs during the 24.10 release-upgrade.

It's simply running a "snap install <package>" for you.
There is a bit of special sauce in selecting a channel for you, but you can easily specify that yourself if you don't like the default.Example: snap install <package> --channel=latest/stable

